# Why my regexp for hyphenated words doesn't work?

Tags: python, regex

I'm writting a regular expression for match with simple words and single hyphenated words using re module of python, so for example in:

```
test_case_input = """the wide-field infrared survey explorer is a nasa
infrared-wavelength space telescope in an earth-orbiting satellite which
performed an all-sky astronomical survey. be careful of -tricky tricky-
hyphens --- be precise."""
```

should be match:

```
test_case_output = ['the', 'wide-field', 'infrared', 'survey', 'explorer',
'is', 'a', 'nasa', 'infrared-wavelength', 'space', 'telescope', 'in', 'an',
'earth-orbiting', 'satellite', 'which', 'performed', 'an', 'all-sky',
'astronomical', 'survey', 'be', 'careful', 'of', 'tricky', 'tricky',
'hyphens', 'be', 'precise']
```

I found a regular expression that match single hyphenated words: **r"[a-z]+-[a-z]+"** and another for the simple words **r"[a-z]+"** then I tried with an or **r"[a-z]+-[a-z]+ | [a-z]+"** but the output is wrong:

```
[' wide', ' infrared', ' survey', ' explorer', ' is', ' a', ' nasa', 
'infrared-wavelength ', ' telescope', ' in', ' an', ' earth', ' satellite',
 ' which', ' an', ' all', ' astronomical', ' survey', ' be', ' careful', ' of',
 ' tricky', ' be', ' precise']
```

If I use gruops: **r"(:?[a-z]+-[a-z]+) | (:?[a-z]+)"** neither, and another solution that I think that shold be work **r"[a-z]+(:?-[a-z]+)?"** neither does.

It is obviously possible, but there is something that I does not clearly understand. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. Your regexes need to be anchored by separators* or you'll match partial words, as is the case now
2. You're not using the proper syntax for a non-capturing group. It's `(?:` not `(:?`

If you address the first problem, you won't need groups at all.

*That is, a blank or beginning/end of string.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
r'[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*'
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex should do it.

```
\b[a-z]+-[a-z]+\b
```

`\b` indicates a word-boundary.